# How do I make Nginx redirect all requests for files which do not exist to a single php file?

Tags: php, nginx, redirect, php-fpm

I have the following nginx vhost config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    access_log /path/to/site/dir/logs/access.log;
    error_log /path/to/site/dir/logs/error.log;

    root /path/to/site/dir/webroot;
    index index.php index.html;

    try_files $uri /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                    return 404;
            }

            fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/site/dir/webroot$fastcgi_script_name;
            include /path/to/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I want to redirect all requests that don't match files which exist to index.php. This works fine for most URIs at the moment, for example:

```
example.com/asd
example.com/asd/123/1.txt
```

Neither of `asd` or `asd/123/1.txt` exist so they get redirected to index.php and that works fine. However, if I put in the url `example.com/asd.php`, it tries to look for `asd.php` and when it can't find it, it returns 404 instead of sending the request to `index.php`.

Is there a way to get `asd.php` to be also sent to `index.php` if `asd.php` doesn't exist?

Comment: You could just rewrite ^ /index.php; instead of return 404;

Comment: See my comment under tyoyengel's answer - I need some way of telling the index.php file to use `error/404` as the path

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Going by your additional comments this sounds like it might be the most optimal way, though it's not a pretty config.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    access_log /path/to/site/dir/logs/access.log;
    error_log /path/to/site/dir/logs/error.log;

    root /path/to/site/dir/webroot;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri @missing;

        fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /path/to/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
    }

    location @missing {
        rewrite ^ /error/404 break;

        fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
        include /path/to/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: there's supposed to be a semicolon at the end of that try_files line

Comment: @jab11 Yep! Added that in now.

Answer (score 5):

Wow, I think all you want to replace that code is:

```
error_page 404 /index.php
```

...if I read what you want correctly.

Comment: This works well, and so I have `error_page 404 /error/404/` which then redirects to `index.php`, but then in the php request_uri (what I use to get the path requested) it has `asd.php` (assuming this is what was typed in and resulted in the 404) and I have no way of getting the `error/404` path to then act on in the php. Is there any way to pass this path to php? I.E. I still want a single front index.php to handle errors as well. How do I tell the index.php that this is an error to handle?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is same as custom error page. You can use the error_page property of nginx to achieve this. Follow the link for more information

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#error_page

Answer (score 2):

It's worked with me!

```
    location /anyfolder {
        error_page 404 /yourhandler.php?fnf=$uri;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are using "try_files" along with an "if" statement in your location. From the documentation, try_files is supposed to be a replacement for if and mod_rewrite style existence check. From the nginx wiki, the "try_files" page ( http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files ):

**"try_files is basically a replacement for the typical mod_rewrite style file/directory existence check. It is supposed to be more efficient than using if - see IfIsEvil"**

Check the "if" wiki page ( http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule#if ):

**"note: Before using if please see the if is evil page and consider using try_files instead."**

So, try remove that if check and just staying with the "try_files". That should check for the existence of any page (including asd.php or anything else endind in .php) and fall back to index.php if it doesn't find it.

Comment: The if statement is to prevent a potential security hole described here: http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2010/07/nginx-primer/ (linked from http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration). It is one exception to the rule of not using if statements inside location blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Richard, according to the Pitfalls guide its recommended to set “cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0″ in php.ini as it resolves a potential [vulnerability](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php) between nginx and php.

Answer (score 0):

I want to redirect all missing php files to custom internal `/error404` error page. I will post my solution found during permutation.

```
error_page 404 /error404;
```

didn't help me. Neither did combinations of `location`, `@missing`, `rewrite` and `break`. But

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    # this is it! $fastcgi_script_name points to my url
    try_files $fastcgi_script_name = /error404; 
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www$fastcgi_script_name;
    ...
    etc.
```