# Nginx redirect all request that does not match a file to a php file

Tags: nginx, redirect, php-fpm, static-files, requests

I'm trying to get all request to:
`http://example.com/downloads/*`
redirect to `http://example.com/downloads/index.php` except if the requested file exist in `/downloads/`

ex:

- `http://example.com/downloads` => `/downloads/index.php`
- `http://example.com/downloads/unknowfile` => `/downloads/index.php`
- `http://example.com/downloads/existingfile` => `/downloads/existingfile`

My current problem is I have either the redirection to php working but static files not served or the opposite.

Here is my current vhost conf: (which redirect fine but static files are send to php and fail)

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    server_name domain.com;
    root /data/www;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }

    location ^~ /downloads {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        try_files $uri @downloads;
    }

    location @downloads {
        rewrite ^ /downloads/index.php;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Precision: static files are symlinks created by /downloads/index.php

Edit: possible [duplicate](https://serverfault.com/questions/218989/how-do-i-make-nginx-redirect-all-requests-for-files-which-do-not-exist-to-a-sing?rq=1), but this solution doesn't seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the index.php as a custom error page in your downloads location (and don't send a 404 header):

```
location ^~ /downloads {
 ...
 fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
 error_page 404 =200 /downloads/index.php;

}
```

Comment: I'm failing to have php interpreting index.php, currently it just return index.php.

Comment: added the line ` fastcgi_intercept_errors on` after a quick search found this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162998](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162998)

Comment: Finally solved problem by using [symfony similar conf](http://wiki.nginx.org/Symfony).
I apply these rules in another vhost with a new subdomain (download.mydomain.com) instead of a subdir.

I put your answer as valid, I didn't tried with fastcgi_intercept_errors but seems like the answer.