# Redirect to specified .php file with try_files if requested .php file not found?

Tags: nginx, redirect, php-fpm, fastcgi

Using nginx I would like to redirect to /redirect.php with try_files if required .php file not found, is it the right way to do so:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
...
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        try_files $uri /redirect.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

However it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What exactly happens when you try this? What is the request you are making? Where exactly does `redirect.php` exist on the filesystem? What is the whole nginx configuration? What do log files tell when you make the request?

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/218989/how-do-i-make-nginx-redirect-all-requests-for-files-which-do-not-exist-to-a-sing

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481678/redirect-url-to-php-only-if-file-does-not-exist-with-nginx

Comment: TLDR I think your snippet would work as just `try_files $uri /redirect.php;` there is no need to mention the `=404` here. Remember to `sudo nginx -t` after config changes and restart the service and/or reboot the server also.

Answer (score 1):

`location \.php$` means that every request ending with `.php` extension will be processed by this block.

Your `try_files` is in the wrong place. You either need to place it under an existing `location /` block or to the `server` block.

Comment: For [security reasons](https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/04/setting-up-php-fastcgi-and-nginx-dont-trust-the-tutorials-check-your-configuration/) I used try_files here...

Comment: I'm pretty sure this answer is misleading, `try_files` is fine there.

Answer (score 0):

This is what we are using in [SlickStack](https://slickstack.io/) to redirect any non-existing `.php` requests over to WordPress for error handing (and 301 redirect management):

```
location ~* \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; ## send .php requests to WordPress if not found
...
}
```

Please note that many answers are floating around that mention `fastcgi_intercept_errors on;`  however that is not necessary when using `try_files` for PHP-FPM routing here.

Ref: https://github.com/littlebizzy/slickstack/edit/master/modules/nginx/sites/production.txt