# Return another code than 404 if file not found on a nginx alias directive

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404

Nginx has a root folder let's say /var/www/mysite1/

I have a file in /var/www/ that I need to be able to serve.
This file sometime exists, sometime does not. If the file is not there, by default nginx is returning a 404. How can I set up a different response code, or a 301 redirection ?

```
location /myfile.txt {
    alias /var/www/myfile.txt;
}
```

Comment: https://nginx.org/r/error_page

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/218989/how-do-i-make-nginx-redirect-all-requests-for-files-which-do-not-exist-to-a-sing

Comment: I know the try uri command, but it tries a url path. My file is in a parent folder of the root so I need to use an alias

Comment: Change `root` and use `try_files`.

Comment: I need to change root inside that location block, right?

Comment: Yes, change inside `location` block.

Comment: ok so I change the `root` in that `location` block and put `try_files $uri =404;` or whatever response code. Last unknown for me is that it risks to make other files in the same folder servable, or am I wrong? I only want to serve that specific file.